# Writing html expression as string in javascript, quotes get confused

Tags: javascript, quote

After writing the html expression as a string in javascript and append it, the quotes get mixed up.

```
var string ="<a href='javascript:;' onclick='toastr.clear('$(this).closest('.toast-bottom-left')');' class='ml-2' id='approve_button'>Kabul Et</a>"
```

After append it takes the following state.

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="toastr.clear(" $(this).closest('.toast-bottom-left')');'="" class="ml-2" id="approve_button">Kabul Et</a>
```

Comment: If it is supported in your browser, use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) with backticks. You don't have to worry about escaping quotes

Comment: Use this and let me know if it works

`var string ="<a href='javascript:;' onclick='toastr.clear($(this).closest(\".toast-bottom-left\"));' class='ml-2' id='approve_button'>Kabul Et</a>"`